# How do I relative the cell value only?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, importrange

For example I have a sheet and there is a col with cell-like A2 and A2 has a hyperlink. A2 value is 'Apple' and the hyperlink is 'stackexchange.com'.

When I am trying to use importrange formula with A2 cell, the cell value+hyperlink, both imported.

How do I import the cell value only which is 'Apple'?

```
=IMPORTRANGE("url", "sheet1!A2")
```

Comment: Can anyone answer it?

Comment: it is not possible to give a precise answer to a vague question ... do your best to explain the problem, for example cell A2 what exactly contains and why you want to import all column A. .. and if you also tell us what is the URL

Comment: @Daniele, question updated. A2 has value = 'Apple' and hyperlink = stackexchange.com
I want to import the A2 to another spreadsheet with value only as 'Apple'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this formula solves your problem:

```
=T(IMPORTRANGE("url", "sheet1!A2"))
```

( a simple `T` placed in front of your formula ).

Sometimes the underline of the text will remain, which you can delete with the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: It does not work on the range.  but work on a single range. Like not work this mode: =T(IMPORTRANGE("url", "sheet1!A2:A10")), this way not import anything.

Comment: if you want to use this type of formula in a range of multiple cells use:  `INDEX(T(IMPORTRANGE("url", "sheet1!A2:A10")))`

Comment: Perfect!!!!! <3